# TortoiseHg - seems to be very slow on Win7

Tags: mercurial, dvcs, tortoisehg

I have recently setup a Mercurial clone with TortoiseHg on our network - it seems to take forever to add files, do commits etc.. It usually hangs for 3-5 minutes at a time & for seem reason it really doesn't like any kind of right-clicking in TortoiseHg.

I am fairly new to Mercurial so there could be some settings to speed this all up but I am not sure of how to best approach this, my pc specs are below:
Intel Core 2 Quad CPU Q8300 @ 2.50Ghz
4GB RAM (3GB Usable)

The actual clone is pretty big - in total just around 200MB, I'm not sure if this large size is causing the slowdown, or the fact that the clone itself isn't on my machine but on our local network.

Any ideas of how best to optimise everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would try to do the same mercurial operations from the command line, to rule out a slow GUI.

We have the same setup here at my work. The "main" repos is on a mapped network drive. Accessing this is slow, so I've made a local clone for fast access and only synchronizing when necessary.

Now when I think about it, why don't you have a clone on your local machine? Isn't that the entire point of dvcs?

Comment: I'm fairly new to Mercurial, it is just setup in this way with all other sites that we don't use any form of DVCS with, although with hindsight it would've been better placing this on my local machine like you said.

I will look into the command line aspect and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Zabs do note that its perfectly fine to keep the shared repos on a network location *and* have your own local clone. No extra setup is required. You you're new I recommend http://hginit.com/ especially the section "Setting up for a Team", it explains what I think you want to do.

Comment: Cheers for that link @mizipor some really good info there! :)